# Renewing certbot certificates manually

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

Thanks in advance for your time and response.

I have generated a certificate using certbot.

```
certbot -d *.mycompany.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns certonly
```

I create the TXT record in my (Amazon Rt53) dns and have created the private and public keys.
I then convert it to .pfx

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey privkey.pem -in fullchain.pem -export -out mycompany.pfx
```

I use the resulting mycompany.pfx in RD gateway and elsewhere in multiple servers (since I have a *.mycompany.com).

Obviously letencrypt expires in 90 days. So I renew the certificate by issuing the same command

```
certbot -d *.mycompany.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns certonly
```

I get the new keys.
I now have to go to the RD gateway server and re-import the new .pfx certificate.
**I have to do this for each server where I have used the certificate.**

**Is this the way this is supposed to work** ? Is there an automated step that I am missing whereby

- I renew and
- all the servers where I have used the certificate renews
  automatically?

Comment: If you have a lot of servers you should look into some form of automated configuration management tool such as chef, puppet, saltstack etc.

Comment: Thanks SuperShoot. Yes, this should be the way to go.

Answer (score -2):

**Automatic renewal of letsencrypt certificates or certbot certificates.**

Certbot can be configured to renew your certificates automatically before they expire.

You can set cron job to renew certificates automatically.

Go to your server and run `sudo crontab -e`. It will open window add following command.

```
0 0 * * * python -c 'import random; import time; time.sleep(random.random() * 3600)' && /home/centos/certbot/certbot-auto renew >> /var/log/auto-renewal-cron 2>&1
```

You can get cron command by selecting system & software based on your OS like below screenshot: https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/osx-apache.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response Mr.Mayank. My question was more concerned about the renewal of certificates on multiple servers. Using ansible or chef as suggested by SuperShot would be the way to go.